# Styling alternate rows for a PanelGridLayout in Oracle ADf

Tags: user-interface, oracle-adf

How do I give different background colors to alternate rows? I'm using <af:panelGridLayout>. All odd rows should have a grey background and even rows should have white background color. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 <af:panelGridLayout id="pgl7">
                  <af:gridRow marginTop="0px" height="auto" id="gr13">
                    <af:gridCell marginStart="0px" marginEnd="0px" width="100%"
                                 id="gc25" styleClass="grey-cells">
                      <af:outputText id="ot2" value="Account"/>
                    </af:gridCell>
                  </af:gridRow>
                  <af:gridRow marginTop="5px" height="auto" id="gr15">
                    <af:gridCell marginStart="0px" marginEnd="0px" width="100%"
                                 id="gc26" styleClass="white-cells">
                      <af:outputText value="#{bindings.accountID.inputValue}"
                                     id="ot3"/>
                    </af:gridCell>
                  </af:gridRow>
                  <af:gridRow marginTop="5px" height="auto" id="gr18">
                    <af:gridCell marginStart="0px" marginEnd="0px" width="100%"
                                 id="gc29" styleClass="grey-cells">
                      <af:outputText id="ot1" value="Name"/>
                    </af:gridCell>
                  </af:gridRow>
                  <af:gridRow marginTop="5px" height="auto" id="gr17">
                    <af:gridCell marginStart="0px" marginEnd="0px" width="100%"
                                 id="gc30" styleClass="white-cells">
                      <af:outputText value="#{bindings.accountHolderName.inputValue}"
                                     id="ot5"/>
                    </af:gridCell>
                  </af:gridRow>
                  <af:gridRow marginTop="5px" height="auto" id="gr14">
                    <af:gridCell marginStart="0px" marginEnd="0px" width="100%"
                                 id="gc27" styleClass="grey-cells">
                      <af:outputText value="Email" id="ot6"/>
                    </af:gridCell>
                  </af:gridRow>
                  <af:gridRow marginTop="5px" marginBottom="0px" height="auto"
                              id="gr16">
                    <af:gridCell marginStart="0px" marginEnd="0px" width="100%"
                                 id="gc28" styleClass="white-cells">
                      <af:outputText value="#{bindings.emailId.inputValue}"
                                     id="ot11"/>
                    </af:gridCell>
                  </af:gridRow>
                </af:panelGridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The panelGridLayout is not meant to use this way. It's meant to be used as layout container to position other components. A grid route does not even have the style properties you would need to do this.
You either color each cell of the row, which you have do yourself, out you look into another component like af:table or af:treaTable which do the banding automatically.